# How to get the version number of JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

How can I find out at runtime which version of JavaFX I'm using?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion();
```

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate? Is there any output or exception?

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, but in substance: Classloader exception, can't load com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo. And the program does not start.

Comment: This class is not available by default in Java 18. Code editor error message: *Package 'com.sun.javafx.runtime' is declared in module 'javafx.base', which does not export it to module 'com.example.fxdemo'*

Comment: @BasilBourque yep, this is way too old approach. Please use the system properties.

Answer (score 44):

One of simple ways is to simply read the `javafx.properties` file located in your `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib` directory.

I have Java 1.7 u9 installed at the moment. JavaFX bundled with it is v2.0.3 so the abovementioned file contains the following line:

```
javafx.runtime.version=2.0.3
```

Comment: I installed java 1.8.0-31 and so I'm getting `javafx.runtime.version=8.0.31`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it is. Java 1.8.0 has JavaFX 8 bundled in.

Comment: @DejanLekic To clarify… Some vendors bundle JavaFX libraries with certain editions of their JDK products. Oracle did so in version 8 of their product *Oracle JDK*, then stopped with later versions. Nowadays two of the several JDK vendors, *Azul Systems* and *BellSoft*, bundle the *OpenJFX* (JavaFX)  libraries with some editions of their JDK products across Java versions 8 through the current 21.

Comment: Well, the answer was written 11 years ago... It is probably not relevant any more, same goes for Java.

Answer (score 24):

## `System.getProperty( "javafx.runtime.version" )`

You can get the `javafx.runtime.version` number from a System Property.

Call [`System.getProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)), passing the property name `"javafx.runtime.version"`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class ReportVersion extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    System.out.println("javafx.runtime.version: " + System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version"));
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Note that the System Property access method may cause a security exception if an unsigned application is embedded in a browser or accessed via WebStart, so Sergey's `com.sun` call may be better even though all `com.sun` calls are deprecated and not part of the official JavaFX public API.

*Update*

@assylias comments on Sergey's answer would seem to indicate that Sergey's `com.sun` may cause a security exception if an unsigned application is embedded in a browser or accessed via WebStart.  So perhaps there is no good solution to determining the javafx runtime version when running under those specific conditions.

---

Trashgod wrote a [version check script](https://gist.github.com/trashgod/c3e0fa8480b11f93b9ab08e597a45a5a) which works similarly to this answer and provides a couple more pieces of diagnostic version information from the environment.  The script comes with an ant build script, but the version check application is just a plain JavaFX application.  So, you can ignore the ant build script if you wish and can execute the utility in any compatible JavaFX environment.

Comment: This does not work in a sandboxed applet due to lack of permissions. The slightly modified version `System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version")` does also not work with this error: `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.runtime.version" "read")`