# javafx.scene.control.Pagination not found

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I'm using java 1.7_07 which include javafx 2.2.1.

When I try to import the package javafx.scene.control.Pagination Netbeans doesn't find it. The class is present in the API documentation, I can't see the reason.

Comment: does Netbeans find other javafx classes?

Answer (score 1):

Check your javafx version: [How to get the version number of JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266997/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-javafx)

You may use Java Platform in NetBeans settings being setup to older JavaFX and `Pagination` is a relatively new control.