# How to find out JavaFX version

Tags: javafx, installation

This should be easy, but I can't figure out how.
Is there any way to find out which JavaFX version is installed. And I DON'T mean programmatically via `System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version")` , which returns an empty string on my computer, although JavaFX is installed.

I would rather like to have something like `java -version` on console, but in order to get the JavaFX version.

Alternatively it would be sufficient to know if JavaFX is installed at all. I just have some customers who can't run my swing/javaFX app and would like to tell them to check whether JavaFX is installed.

Comment: I have no idea, but I imagine it would help to know things like what JDK/JRE you're using.

Comment: @dfeuer My jre version is the latest 8. I also know which javaFX is installed on my machine. But I'm looking for a way to find the javaFX version on any machine, so I can tell someone via phone/email do this and that and you will get the JavaFX version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the version number of JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266997/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-javafx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't really do this the same way you do with the Java runtime. The difference is that `java` is a machine executable that launches the JVM. JavaFX is just a set of library classes; it's not really an executable in the same sense.

It looks like the System property that you can read at runtime is kept in `jre/lib/javafx.properties`, so you can do something like

```
cat $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/javafx.properties
```

or whatever the Windows equivalent is, if you're running on Windows. However, if the System property you get at runtime is blank, then I suspect this file doesn't exist. As dfeuer commented, it would help to know your JRE version.

**Update**:
The relationship between JDK/JRE version and JavaFX version is as follows.

Beginning with JRE 1.7.0 update 6, JavaFX was included with the JRE, but was not on the classpath. So for JRE 1.7.0, update 6 and later, the `jfxrt.jar` file is included in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib`. The `javafx.properties` file which contains the JavaFX version information is in the same directory, though in theory at least the JRE version will determine the JavaFX version (since they were shipped together).

Just inspecting the JDK 1.7.0 versions I have installed on my machine, the mapping from JDK version to JavaFX version is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.0
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.4
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.4
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.5
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.7
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.21
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.25
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.40
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=2.2.45
```

Beginning with JRE 1.8.0, JavaFX was included with the JRE and was placed on the classpath; so it's effectively a full part of the core libraries. In version 1.8.0, the `jfxrt.jar` file is in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` (which automatically makes it part of the classpath). The `javafx.properties` file which contains the JavaFX version information is still in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib`. The version numbering for JavaFX in version 1.8.0 (appears to) simply mimic the JRE version:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk  javafx.runtime.version=8.0.0
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=8.0.5
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk   javafx.runtime.version=8.0.20
```

So with your customers, you can simply ask them to do `java -version` and for the most part, you'll be able to deduce the JavaFX version. On some rare occasions you may need to dig a little deeper.

A sort-of-related note: if you are shipping an application to customers and you need to determine a specific version, consider using a [self contained application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm), in which you include a JRE (and JavaFX runtime) with the application.

Comment: My jre is the latest 8. But how does that help, when trying to get the installed JavaFX version on a customer's machine? I'd like to have something simple I can instrcut the customer to do via phone or email, but apparently there's no simple solution. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I updated the answer to show the relationship between JRE version and JavaFX version.

Comment: This is really helpful. Regarding the self contained application, I was thinking about using Launch4J to create an exe wrapper, which has a java version check included and can redirect to the java download page if the version does not fit the requirements

Comment: For JavaFX applications, I strongly recommend using either `javafxpackager`, or its Ant task wrapper. Wizards for the ant task are built into JavaFX projects in NetBeans or in Eclipse (the latter if you use the e(fx)clipse plugin). This also includes the option to build the "self-contained" application which bundles the JRE and wraps it as an .exe or .dmg file.

Comment: In reading your comments on asking a client to go somewhere and download a check, why not just use the one provided by java?  http://www.java.com/verify

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 18.04 the JavaFX version can be found in /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.properties. A simple command should show you the version you have.

```
$ cat /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.properties
javafx.version=11.0.2-internal
javafx.runtime.version=11.0.2-internal+0-2019-02-19-093139
javafx.runtime.build=0
```

Perhaps your installation has something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbeans 15 on Windows 10, look in the file:
C:\Program Files\NetBeans-15\netbeans\javafx\VERSION.txt

On my machine, it contains 11

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can go into Control Panel and click "Programs and Features"; if you have JavaFX installed, it should be there. The fifth column is the Version.