# JavaFX - Set the number of rows displayed

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I use ComboBox, once put into a list (FXCollections.observableArrayList) with 2 short lines, then a list with a large number of rows.

After I change from the list with 2 to list with 15 (or more) - I see only 2 line each time inside ComboBox.

How do I change this setting? How display 4 or more?

Relevance code:

```
cbQueriesOptions.getItems().clear();
cbQueriesOptions.getItems().addAll(itemsQueriesOptionsString);
cbQueriesOptions.setVisible(true);

cbQueriesOptions.setDisable(true);
cbQueriesOptions.getItems().clear();
cbQueriesOptions.getItems().addAll(itemsQueriesOptionsAll);
```

[image]

Comment: Which JavaFX version are you using? I can't replicate the issue in `1.8.0_25`.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Where I check the version?

Comment: [You can follow the steps illustrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266997/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-javafx)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha javafx.runtime.version: 8.0.40-ea-b11

Comment: [I created a MCVE](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/c753626fb0c1389249ad) and I cannot replicate the issue. Can you please modify it to replicate your issue? or create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your own to show the behavior.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha it's happened with your code too. When I click on "refill large" it's show a long list, after that I click on "refill small" and it's only 3 on a long empty list.... why??

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Can I limit it with css style?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. If you upgrade to the full release of 1.8.0_40 (instead of the prerelease you currently have), does it fix the problem?

Comment: @James_D How to upgrade?

Comment: Go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and download the appropriate version for your platform.