# Navigating JavaFX Versions: Unraveling Warnings and Ensuring Compatibility

Tags: java, javafx

I'm now developing a java application using javaFX in the UI, my program is running but I get this warning all the time when I run it :

```
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 21 by JavaFX runtime of version 17.0.6
Oct 27, 2023 4:44:21 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
```

I try to download this 21 version of sdk and it still has the same problem.

Comment: See: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).  Provide the *complete* stack trace in the question as text formatted as code.  Provide a [mcve].  Write [properly formatted text](https://www.grammarly.com) (I [updated your question text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77375529/revisions)).  Use correct tags (you are not using the `javafx-2` version of Java, I deleted that tag).

Comment: While you may have downloaded JavaFX 21, the message is clear:  You are not, in fact, running the program with JavaFX 21.  If you describe the steps you took to make use of JavaFX 21, we may be able to help you.

Comment: See: [*How to get the version number of JavaFX?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11266997/642706)

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

This warning occurs if you are using not the same version in JavaFX dependencies, installed JDK and or compile version of your project.

Why is this warning important? Your fxml document is allowed to use features from JFX 21, but your SDK is just JFX 17.

This means, that your compiled application may have bugs because it maybe uses JFX 21 features, but it does not support them, because it uses JFX 17. And you will not notice that during development. :(

**Solution 1:**

Tell your fxml file to use JFX 17! To do that, open your fxml file and change the needed information in the root tag:

Take a look at the attribute `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17"`. The number "17" is the supported JavaFX version. There can be "21" for example too. In your case, put 17 there.

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.wedasoft.project.views.main.MainViewController">
     ...
</BorderPane>
```

**Solution 2:**

Change the compile verion of your JavaFX dependencies to 21. To do that, take a look in your build.gradle / pom.xml file and change the version.

Example for build.gradle:

```
ext {
    javaFxVersion = '17.0.8'
}
javafx {
    version = "${javaFxVersion}"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}
```

Example for pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```